# Converting from List[Vector[T]] to Vector[List[T]] in a generic way

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to figure out if I can convert `List(Vector(1), Vector(2,3))` to `Vector(List(1), List(2,3))` or any two traversable classes in a generic way.

This is what I have so far:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.breakOut
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def f[A, CC[X] <: Traversable[X], DD[Y] <: Traversable[Y]](outer: DD[CC[A]])
  (implicit cbf1: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[_], A, DD[A]],
  cbf2: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[_], DD[A], CC[DD[A]]])
  : CC[DD[A]] = {
  val builder2 = cbf2()
  outer.foreach { inner =>
    val builder1 = cbf1()
    builder1 ++= inner
    builder2 += builder1.result
  }
  builder2.result
}

f(Vector(List(1), List(2,3)))(breakOut, breakOut) 
f(ListBuffer(Vector(1), Vector(2,3)))(breakOut, breakOut)
```

If I remove the breakOuts, it will not compile:

```
f(Vector(List(1), List(2,3))) // won't work
```

*could not find implicit value for parameter cbf1: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[_],Int,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]]*

Are there implicits I can import? Any other way to approach this problem that would not require the breakOuts?

---

*edit based on retronym's answer:*

```
import scalaz.CanBuildAnySelf
def f[A, CC[X] <: Traversable[X] : CanBuildAnySelf, 
         DD[Y] <: Traversable[Y] : CanBuildAnySelf](outer: DD[CC[A]])
           : CC[DD[A]] = {
  val builder2 = implicitly[CanBuildAnySelf[CC]].builder[DD[A], DD[A]].apply()
  outer.foreach { inner =>
    val builder1 = implicitly[CanBuildAnySelf[DD]].builder[A, A].apply()
    builder1 ++= inner
    builder2 += builder1.result
  }
  builder2.result
}
```

It's nice and impressive to see that the CanBuildAnySelf context bound can be used completely separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We get it done in Scalaz, so it's certainly possible.

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> List(Vector(1, 2, 3)).sequence
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[List[Int]] = Vector(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))

scala> Seq(List(1), List(3)).sequence
res2: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 3))

scala> Vector(ArraySeq(1, 2, 3)).sequence
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = ArraySeq(Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(1, 2, 3))
```

We only consider 'well-behaved' collections, that is ones that can contain arbitrary element types, unlike `BitSet`. This is witnessed with https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/CanBuildAnySelf.scala

Comment: `CanBuildAnySelf` is basically about 10 lines of code and it works like a charm. Very impressive.

Comment: Just avert thine eyes from the `asInstanceOf`!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
val l = List(Vector(1), Vector(2, 3))
val v = Vector((for (v <- l) yield v.toList): _*)
```

Comment: I'm looking to write a function that would do the same in a generic way for different types.